# Generate PDF from HTML content in SP online

Tags: sharepoint-online, pdf, nintex

There is a requirement to generate a PDF and upload into a document library from dynamic HTML content created using Nintex workflow in SP online.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge neither Nintex, nor SharePoint Online provide functionality to do this natively, so you have to use 3rd party functionality or write a helluva lot of code.

I wrote a couple of blog posts on this subject recently as Converting HTML in SP Online is a hot topic because it makes content generation very easy.

Have a look at the following:

- [Converting SharePoint Online Pages / Items to PDF](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2017/10/converting-sharepoint-online-pages.html) (this also works for custom HTML)
- [Integrating this with Nintex Workflow for Office 365](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2017/08/use-nintex-workflow-for-office-365-to.html) (you will need to make minor changes to invoke a slightly different REST endpoint.

There is a couple of things to take into account. Nintex for Office 365 currently does not support direct integration with third party software like their on-premise products do. Therefore you have to use the workaround in the 2nd blog post linked to above to invoke a REST API. It is all a bit messy, another option may be to create a SharePoint Designer workflow (which does support 3rd party components) and invoke that workflow from Nintex Workflow.

The other thing to take into account is that I wrote those blog posts and worked on the product mentioned, so consider me biased (but very knowledgeable on the topic).

Comment: If the content is stored in a list, then you can use the Nintex document generation add-on. you will need to verify you own a license, otherwise it will not appear as an option. otherwise, a 3rd party component is your only option.